# How to make a program which prints prime numbers in given range

Tags: python, numbers

I want to make a program as an exercise which prints all prime numbers in range of given limit(parameter). Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find all prime numbers in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427890/how-can-i-find-all-prime-numbers-in-a-given-range)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```py
#prime numbers
prime = list()

for x in range(1, 100):
    for a in range(2, x):
        if x % a == 0:
            break
    else:
        prime.append(x)
print(prime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this list comprehension to find prime numbers in given range;

```
def prime_generator(number):
   return [x for x in range(2, number) if not any(x % y == 0 for y in range(2, int(x/2)+1))]

In: prime_generator(30)
Out: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```